# How to open a local folder using Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have a photo within Google Earth. I would like to be able to click the photo or description to open the folder directory. I believe the *href* needs to be modified. How can the code be modified to open the local folder?

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEz74.png)

`<a href="file:///C:/Temp">Click Here to open Folder</a>
<img style="max-width:500px;" src="file:///C:/Temp/Photo1.jpg">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to a local folder only if you change two of the default settings.
Open Google Earth and select Menu / Tools / Options / General

- In Display panel, check "**Show Web Results in external Browser**" option
- In Placemark Balloons panel, check "**Allow Access to local files and personal data**" option

Then create a KML file in a text editor (such as the following) and launch it in Google Earth.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>      
    <description><![CDATA[

<a href="file:///C:/Temp">Click Here to open Folder</a>
<img style="max-width:500px;" src="file:///C:/Temp/Photo1.jpg">

      ]]>
    </description>  
    ...
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

For more details on using HTML in KML description balloon, see [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#descriptionexample).